# Interaction Between Two Bar Magnets

Tags: electromagnetism, forces

How would one describe the [interaction between two bar magnets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_between_magnets)? In the E&M course I took we described quite a few very basic electric interactions, but things that I would have thought of as being basic magnetic interactions didn't end up being discussed. What's the best way we have of described the force between two bar magnets, perhaps parallel, and some nontrivial distance apart?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the WP on [Force between two magnets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_between_magnets)?

Comment: Anthony, Googling the title of your question returns the Wikipedia article BMS links as the very first hit. This comes awfully close to qualifying as [insufficient effort](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/what-counts-as-sufficient-prior-research-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Yeah, I think I have reas it before and thought it mentioned approximations I didn't like...but I could be wrong. I'm sorry if I was mistaken.

Comment: @Anthony You could refine your question by explaining what was missing or unclear for you in that description.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17309/2451 . More on force between two magnets: http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+force+two+magnets