# What is the source for magnetic energy?

Tags: electrons

*"The electron around the nucleus is in a quantized energy level and can change it only if an external interaction intervenes."*  That is OK but when there is a magnet, it has energy of attracting iron particles for months and years (natural magnet) just by right order of atoms. Where this energy come from? In nature we have to spend one sort of energy to gain another form, but in a magnet what is spending? Thanks

Comment: Comment to the update(v2): This is essentially a duplicate of e.g. [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/35/2451) Phys.SE post.